# Create PostgreSQL backup files with timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, backup

I'm doing a dump like this `pg_dump prod-db -U postgres > prod-db.sql`, but would be cool if I could do a dump like `pg_dump prod-db -U postgres > prod-db-{date}.sql` and be able to generate a file like `prod-db-06-02-13.sql` via shell...
I have no idea on how to start nor where to looking for. Any ideas, links, docs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
pg_dump prod-db -U postgres > prod-db-$(date +%d-%m-%y).sql
```

Here's [the date manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html), for other format options.

Answer (score 4):

Use backticks and the `date` command.

i.e.

```
pg_dump prod-db -U postgres > prod-db-`date +%d-%m-%y`.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_dump --file="{data_source}-{timestamp}-dump.sql"
```